webView cannot open camera
// HTTPS Configuration
const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('D:/projects/webApp/OpenSSL-Win64/bin/server.key'), // Path to your server private key
    cert: fs.readFileSync('D:/projects/webApp/OpenSSL-Win64/bin/server.crt') // Path to your server SSL certificate
};

// Start HTTPS server
const port = 3000;

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on https://localhost:${port}`);
});  

i have something like this but listens to a public ip and a port now i have it as http i have create a webview apk from my site that listens on this port. In this program i have functions like donwload from server and user could takephotos and send to the server to his folder. i Can't use the camera and the filedownload can i use these functions without https in android webview?
i want to could open the camera and use the download functions via webview app without https for now because i have host it in server and listens on ip address not on a domain name with certificates enabled

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic
